# Amazon Advertise API Product add

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazonsellercentral

I am to develop a PPC software based on AMAZON PPC API. I want to setup sandbox environment for testing. Everything is fine but when I am adding product adds then I got missing_decoration status but for living statistics Ad_Status_Live.
How can I achieve the same status in sandbox also?